# Attach Comments to Email via Outlook Add-In developed via C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin

I am working on developing an Add-In for Outlook using Visual Studio 2013. My requirements are to attach comments/ notes to a specific email so that I can specify if that person is contact via phone on a specific day/time. I am not sure if this can be done, if yes, how? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would like to display the information and if it's meant for personal or organizational use, but if the information is based on the contact you could create a database/xml/ini with this information or just add notes to the contact item. Then you could create a Ribbon button that displays a messagebox/winform that gets that information from where your stored the information based on the contacts of the email that is currently selected.

You could either have an application outside of Outlook or another ribbon button to display a form to create/update the information on the database.

If you want the information to appear on the ribbon itself, it could be done but gets a little trickier.

[Here is some information on creating XML buttons for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx).

Comment: Seems perfect. I was also thinking something in the same direction.